# what locale does I18n.locale.to_s in rails return

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I am not able to get what locale string `I18n.locale.to_s` returns. Is it the locale where the code runs (ie. the locale of the server where the code is deployed) or is it fetching locale from the request (the locale from where the URL is requested)?

I believe it should be the server's locale like if a user from us(en_US) hits a server running in JP(ja_JP), `I18n.locale.to_s` should return locale as JP. Correct me if my assumption is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. Unless you are using additional code (an extra gem for instance), Rails doesn't do a lookup on the IP address of the visitor, nor does it take into account anything to do with the browser of the visitor.

When you call `I18n.locale.to_s` in a controller, or elsewhere in the code, you'll get the default locale back for the location of the server. However, if you want to change locale for the current visitor based on, say, them clicking a link to change it by sending a `:locale` parameter with the request, you could do this:

```
before_action :set_locale

def set_locale
  I18n.locale = params[:locale] || I18n.default_locale
end
```

Then all calls to `I18n.locale.to_s` within that request would now respond with the overriden locale.

Comment: @sergio You're fast! I was in the middle of fixing that myself.

Comment: answers my query perfectly, Good to know an extra piece of info for overriding locale. :)

Comment: @stef: actually, I was in the middle of writing a similar answer. That's how I saw yours as soon as it was posted. :)